# Why is IDbSet<T> missing FindAsync?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

A "work-around" to this question was posted on this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800967/no-findasync-method-on-idbsett) that involved creating your own `IDbSet` interface and class and inheriting from EF's versions. It is a good answer, but the original question remains: Is there a reason that the `FindAsync()` method is omitted from the `IDbSet<T>` interface?

I thought it was an oversight and I keep expecting it to be added in the next version, but 6.1.3 just arrived a couple days ago and is still missing `FindAsync()` on the `IDbSet<T>` interface. There has to be a logical reason I'm overlooking.

Comment: I'm facing same issue, did you figure this out?

Comment: @Chandru, no, never found a reason. However, in EF6 most of the DbContext properties and methods are marked as `virtual` so they can be overridden with a mocking framework like Moq.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I will share if I found anything useful.